# Bootstrap Scrollspy stopped working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, scrollspy

I'm trying to use scrollspy and thought that I did everything right, but obviously I didn't... It actually worked at first but it's been a while and I've added and subtracted heaps, so not sure what caused it. Here's my code

```
<body id="home" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#primary-nav" data-offset="20">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="primary-nav">
        <div class = container> 
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle nav</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>  
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#featured"><span class="logo">reflections</span></a>
            </div><!--navbar-header-->
        </div><!--container-->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#home"></a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#villa">OUR VILLA</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#photos">PHOTOS</a> 
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#location">OUR LOCATION</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!---navbar-collapse--->
    </nav>
```

I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site please.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I haven't uploaded it yet. I could post my nav styling but it's **long**. Do you think it's a CSS feature causing this?

Comment: I think it's a file path issue. Post your head section here.

Comment: @Andrew Lyndem here: `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css">
</head>`

Comment: hmmmm. Can you give me a link to the site?

Comment: Also, load the page, right click anywhere and click "Inspect". Then check "console" and tell me what errors you're getting.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem, here are the console errors:
1. lg-thumbnail.min.js:4 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined(anonymous function) @ lg-thumbnail.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ lg-thumbnail.min.js:4
2.lg-fullscreen.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined(anonymous function) @ lg-fullscreen.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ lg-fullscreen.min.js:4
something.html:250 
thanks for help btw.

Comment: It seems there's an issue with the JS of your site. Check if all files and js functions.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem the warnings belong to 2 files I've removed cause I decided not to use those specific plungins. I have just fixed them (deleted them completely but the issue remains. I ve also tried commenting all the js sections out one by one to see if it changes anything, but it didnt. I'm getting pretty hopeless here so maybe I can upload it early...

Comment: It's very hard for me to understand what is going on unless I can check the site. If you can provide me with a demo link to the site, maybe I can pinpoint the issue and help you further. Cheers

Comment: Hi, @AndrewLyndem it's not quite finished, but here is the website: [devin-watson.site](http://devin-watson.site/) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollspy is working fine DWatson. Add this style property to your css:

```
.navbar-nav>li.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

and you will notice the color changing accordingly when you scroll.